# exactly $k$ distinct values in $n$ $n$-sided dices

Tags: probability, dice

We roll $n$ $n$-sided dices. What is the probability of getting exactly $k$ different values? From the union bound (as every possible $k$ sequence might contain the $k$ different results), I think the probability should relate to $\binom {n}{k}$. On the other hand if we had $k$ throws, the probability would be something like $\frac{k-1}{k} \cdot \frac{k-2}{k} \cdots \frac{1}{k}$. So now is it something like $\binom {n}{k} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \cdots \frac{n-k-1}{n}$? I think I am missing the $n-k$ failures part. Would it be $ \binom{n}{n-k} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \cdots \frac{n-k-1}{n}$   . Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. If $n>k$, then by Dirichlet principle some values will repeat.

Comment: n is greater than k. I want the event of having exactly k distinct ones. (k distinct values and n-k repetitions).

Comment: Does, for $k=2$ and $n=4$, the sequence 1333 or the sequence 1233 satisfy the conditions ?

Comment: Only the first one does. The second has 3 distinct values.
Let k =100 and n=1000. We demand for exactly 100 different oucomes. Imagine a set containing exactly 100 members {x,y},where x's are pairwise different numbers, and y's are the times x appeared in the 1000 throws. Notice that $\sum y$ = 1000. So what is the probability of this set having cardinality exactly 100 with 1000 rolls?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended Comment just to help you get started.

Let $n = 6$ and $k = 1.$ That means getting the same result on
all $6$ rolls of an ordinary fair cubical die: $6(1/6)^6 = 0.0001286.$

Let $n = 6$ and $k = 6.$ That means getting all different faces
in $6$ such rolls: $6!/6^6 =  0.0154321.$

From there is gets a little more complicated. Make sure you exclude
the results you don't want as well as providing for the ones you do.
And make sure the numerator counts ordered arrangements if the
denominator does.

Maybe try $k=2$ or $k=5$ next. Do it soon to learn something
before another Answers spoils the fun.

Below are results from a million simulations in R of the experiment
for $n = 6,$ giving *approximate* probabilities for various values of $k.$ (You can trust the first 2 or 3 decimal places, sometimes 4.) The results
are not far off for $k=1$ and $k=6$ above. You might want to use it as a reality check as you try
different combinatorial approaches.

```
 m = 10^6;  n = 6;  k = 3;  u = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   faces = sample(1:n, n, rep=T)
   u[i] = length(unique(faces)) }
 table(u)/m
 ## u
 ##        1        2        3        4        5        6 
 ## 0.000114 0.019808 0.230756 0.501897 0.231939 0.015486
```